# Space pattern on webpage with PERL CGI

Tags: perl

As i am working on cgi perl i am trying align two sequences and print their out put on web page but their may be some prob with this part because i am not getting my desired format of output on web page. if I am trying  print this output on a txt file then its coming in right way as I want .

**code having problem**

```
print "[$id]\n";
print "Length = $M\n\n";
print "Score = $bitS bits ($S), Expect = $Eval\n";
print "Identities = $matchnum/$totlen ($ipct%), Positives = $sim/$totlen ($Ppct%), Gaps = $gapnum/$totlen ($Gpct%)\n\n";
print "Query ";
print "$_"foreach @align1;
print "\n";
print "      ";
print "$_"foreach @homol;
print "\n";
print "Sbjct ";
print "$_"foreach @align2;
print "\n\n\n";`
```

**input1** `YLGGAILAEVIGTTLMKFSEGFTRLWPSVGTIICYCASFWLLAQTLAYIPTGIAYAIWSG`

**input2** `MKWLILVLGILSNASASVLVKYAMLPPRRFPSLADPMAALSNWPFWLGLALYGGAFLLYA`

**output should be like this only :**

```
Score = 82.4 bits (202), Expect = 3.973330e-025
Identities = 40/40 (100.0%), Positives = 40/40 (100.0%), Gaps = 0/40 (0.0%)
Query MTDTTLPPGGDAADRVEPVDIQQEMQRSYIDYAMSVIVGR

      ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Sbjct MTDTTLPPGGDAADRVEPVDIQQEMQRSYIDYAMSVIVGR
```

**As on my web page I am getting in this way**

```
Score = 82.4 bits (202), Expect = 3.973330e-025 Identities = 40/40 (100.0%), Positives = 40/40 (100.0%), Gaps = 0/40 (0.0%) Query MTDTTLPPGGDAADRVEPVDIQQEMQRSYIDYAMSVIVGR  |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| Sbjct MTDTTLPPGGDAADRVEPVDIQQEMQRSYIDYAMSVIVGR
```

Answer (score 5):

What content-type header are you returning? If you tell the browser to expect HTML, then it will interpret your data as HTML and ignore any whitespace (including newlines).

If you're sending plain text, then you should send a content-type of text/plain.

Answer (score 1):

You're not outputting a .txt file, though, you're trying to output HTML, so you have to output HTML tags like <p>, <br /> and <pre> to structure it properly. Wrapping the entire output in <pre> tags ought to get you what you want, here, I.e. add:

```
print "<pre>\n";
```

at the beginning, and:

```
print "</pre>\n";
```

at the end, preferably with full <html> and <body> tags outside of that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks paul-griffiths and Dave Cross for sharing your knowledge. As earlier I used`<Br>`and`<p>` tags but i was getting same error in display of alignment ... at last, Solve My Problem with`<pre>`tag.... Thanks again ....